# "'" is displayed as u0027 in facebook app - how to fix that?

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook app that is displaying random quotes - it is written in php.

One quote in the database looks like this:

"There**'**s only one rule in photography - never develop colour film in chicken noodle soup.
- Freeman Patterson"

When it is seen on facebook it looks like this:

"There**u0027**s only one rule in photography - never develop colour film in chicken noodle soup.
 - Freeman Patterson"

How do I fix it?

Comment: Yes JavaScript  is used.

Comment: I need more info before I can help.  Is this an FBML app? If so, post the FBML you're using.  Is javascript processing the strings?  Are they loaded via ajax?

Comment: We are using Javascript object notation and Facebook markup language.  We are using AJAX and the javascript does do some string manipulation.  
Perhaps the backslash ('\') character is being filtered away because the character should be apostrophe and \u0027 is the unicode for apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a case of needing to HTML Encode that character before passing it to Facebook?

```
htmlentities( $quote_string , ENT_QUOTES );
```

Which, in the case of the above would return

```
$str = "There's only one rule in photography - never develop colour film in chicken noodle soup. - Freeman Patterson";
$ret = htmlentities( $str , ENT_QUOTES );
echo $ret;
```

Would return:

> There's only one rule in photography - never develop colour film in chicken noodle soup. - Freeman Patterson